# How to query more than 5000 records in Flex Salesforce app?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, salesforce

I've run into an issue where Salesforce will only return 1000 records to my flex app from a query.  I'd like to get more than that (like 5000-10000).  Is this possible?

Here is what I have tried (app is an F3WebApplication)
note:this code does work, I just need it to return more results:

```
app.wrapper.query(query, 
        new mx.rpc.Responder(
            function(rows:ArrayCollection):void {
                if(user_list != null){
                    filteredList = addOwnerData(rows);
                    filteredList = PutChildrenWithParents(filteredList);
                } else {
                    filteredList = PutChildrenWithParents(rows);
                }

                my_accounts_raw = new ArrayCollection(filteredList.toArray());
                refreshSearchData(filteredList);
            },
            function():void{_status = "apex error!";}
        )
    );   
}
```

I've also tried app.connection.Query to then use queryMore but can't get that to work at all.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

connection has access to query and queryMore, and the callback gets queryResult instead of the arrayCollection.  Logic goes something like:

```
app.connection.query("SELECT Id, Name from ETC__c", new SfdcAsyncResponder(getResult,showError));
```

public function getResult(results:QueryResult):void {
  if(!results.done) {app.connection.queryMore(results.queryLocator,new SfdcAsyncResponder(getResult,showError));}
  / ... /
}

Note that if you aren't using the wrapper functionality, you'll probably need to coordinate offline data manually (if this is AIR).

HTH

Answer (score 1):

query/queryMore is the way to go, you'll need the queryLocator value from the first query result in order to call queryMore.

Comment: Can I get the querylocator from F3WebApplication.wrapper or do I need to use F3WebApplication.connection?  I can't find documentation for the latter.